# How an array is "tightly packed" in Solidity

Tags: sha256, sha, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to create a hash (sha256) of an array but I don't understand how it works.

for example :

```
pragma solidity 0.4.11;
contract test { bytes32 public hash; bytes32 public hash2; bytes32 public hash3; bytes32 public hash4;
function test () {
    address[2] memory _add;
    _add[0] = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c;
    _add[1] = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c;
    hash = sha256(_add[0],_add[1]);
    hash2 = sha256(_add);

    _add[0] = 0;
    _add[1] = 0;
    hash3 = sha256(_add[0],_add[1]);
    hash4 = sha256(_add);
}
```

hash is different from hash2 and hash3 is different from hash4... why?

The "tightly packed" data should result in the same hash ... no?

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue was that all the elements of the array are converted to Bytes32 (adding a padding of zeros)...

So basically :

data before hash = ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733cca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c

data before hash2 = 000000000000000000000000ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c000000000000000000000000ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c

data before hash3 = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

data before hash4 = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

"Tightly packed" no longer applies when dealing with an array. You must zerofill to 32 bytes.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find the docs to validate that, so all I can do is give an example to show it works.

*Side Note: Are you sure you want `sha256` instead of `keccak256`, which is used most other places in Ethereum?*

### Demo

I'll demonstrate with `sha3` (the same as `keccak256`), but the concept is the same.

**Baseline**

In Remix, you'll find that:

```
sha3([0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c, 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c]);
```

gives the result: `0x77e5189111eb6557e8a637b27ef8fbb15bc61d61c2f00cc48878f3a296e5e0ca`

**Rebuild, with Web3.py**

```
from web3 import Web3, IPCProvider

web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())

addr = 'ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c'
zerofilled = addr.zfill(64)  # 64 hex chars == 32 bytes
two_packed = zerofilled * 2

sha = web3.sha3('0x' + two_packed, encoding='hex')
assert sha == '0x77e5189111eb6557e8a637b27ef8fbb15bc61d61c2f00cc48878f3a296e5e0ca'
```

For what it's worth, you can also get the result with:

```
web3.soliditySha3(
  ['address[2]'],
  [[
    '0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c',
    '0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c',
  ]],
)
```

Comment: Thank you for this very well documented answer!